# iPhone auto config script for mail/pop3/smtp settings

Tags: iphone

how can I write a script to auto-config the mail settings in iPhone?

Here's the thing:

I have to provide a script for employee in my company to download it and automatically setup the pop3/smtp settings in iPhone. I tried use "iphone auto config" keywords to search but find nothing-related. Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the iPhone configuration utility is what I need:
http://www.apple.com/support/iphone/enterprise/

and here's a tutorial:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w_int5sftO0